# How do I use dma_alloc_attr() with DMA_ATTR_NO_KERNEL_MAPPING?

Tags: c, memory-management, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, dma

I want to use `DMA_ATTR_NO_KERNEL_MAPPING` for memory allocation. According to [the kernel documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/DMA-attributes.txt), I have to use `dma_mmap_attrs()`, but it requires `struct vm_area_struct` as one of its argument. How can I use it?

```
dma_addr_t phys;
void *virt;
void *tmp_virt;
struct vm_area_struct *vma;

pr_debug("pmap: cma: request to alloc %s for size 0x%08x\n",
         info->name, info->size);

if(strcmp(info->name,"video") == 0)
{
    pr_debug("video allocation.....\n");
    tmp_virt = dma_alloc_attrs(pmap_device, info->size, &phys, GFP_KERNEL,
                        DMA_ATTR_NO_KERNEL_MAPPING | DMA_ATTR_FORCE_CONTIGUOUS);

    virt = dma_mmap_attrs(pmap_device, vma, tmp_virt, &phys, info->size,
                        DMA_ATTR_NO_KERNEL_MAPPING | DMA_ATTR_FORCE_CONTIGUOUS);

}
```

I am requesting memory allocation using the ioctl call from user space, and then a kernel panic occurs with a system reboot.

How do I use `DMA_ATTR_NO_KERNEL_MAPPING` for user space allocation using ioctl?

In my sample driver code I am declaring `struct vm_area_struct *vma`. Is that correct?

Comment: Your variable `vma` does not point anywhere, therefore passing it to `dma_mmap_attrs` that attempts to dereference it leads to bad things happening. Maybe you should declare it as a non-pointer `struct vm_area_struct` and assign correct values to its fields and then pass its address to `dma_mmap_attrs`. See [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/kernel/dma/mapping.c#L198) for the source

Comment: declare it as non-pointer but result is same. its correct to pass empty vma ? any reference how to use it.

Comment: I guess it's not correct to pass unitialized `vma`. I don't know what values to initialize it with, look at the docs or sources for pointers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you used DMA_ATTR_NO_KERNEL_MAPPING in dma_alloc_attr(), it means that you dont want virtual mapping for the allocated area. DMA_ATTR_NO_KERNEL_MAPPING only used again to mapped with user space memory, no direct api to mapped it with kernel space memory.

if user space want to mapped it virtually, below are the options.

1. Use dma_mmap_attr() in driver you have to used .map = map_user_space_function()
   and then use dma_mmap_attr() in that function, it will mapped to user space virtual memory.
2. Use get_vm_area() in driver and use dma_mmap_attr() in which used the vm_area return by get_vm_area().